# How to read in a Bit field to create a checkbox

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a field in my SQL database that is a BIT field.

I want to read in that field.  If 1 then checkbox is true, else false.

I started off with this code, but getting error.  Any advice on how to do this?

```
        If (MyReader["TArchive"] == 1) then
```

Regards
Tea

Comment: What error it is throwing? You can use MyReader.GetBoolean(index) if you are sure with index or you can also convert to value to boolean Convert.ToBoolean(MyReader["TArchive"]) == true. Just debug and check what value is coming.

Comment: it doesn't like the ==.  I want to say If (MyReader["TArchive"] is TRUE) then checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
myCheckbox.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(MyReader["TArchive"]);
```

Comment: Interesting.  Even though its read data from a BIT field, you still have to convert to Boolean?

Comment: Alternative to `MyReader.GetBoolean("TArchive")` you can do it in this way too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
If (MyReader.GetBoolean("TArchive")) // returns true if value is 1
{
           // checkbox true
}
else
{
    // checkbox false
}
```

Not tested but [GetBoolean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.getboolean%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) does this automatically.

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.GetBoolean(int)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Please refer the link I have added for  GetBoolean